# Best image format for face detection and face recognition with the DeepFace library

Tags: python

I'm using the DeepFace library for face recognition and detection.

I was wondering if there is a better format (png, jpg, etc) than others to get better results.

Is there a preferred image format for face recognition and face detection generally? and specifically in this library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python images are processed as bit bitmaps using the colour depth of the graphic system. Converting a PNG image to a bitmap is really fast(20 x times) when compared to jpegs.

[Deepace](https://github.com/serengil/deepface) - Currently accepting only 2 types of image input formats. PNG/Jpeg. there is no way you can use other formats images directly as you are using thier libraries. If you want to use another input formats so then atlast you need to convert either to PNG or Jpeg to give input to the functions. Which may costs you extra execution time while bringing other format images to PNG/Jpegs.

If want to improve the face recognition and face detection with deepface library then use some [preprocessing filters](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html)

Some of the filters you can try for better results. [utlimate guide](https://www.kaggle.com/code/soumya9977/deep-dive-in-image-preprocessing-using-opencv)

- Grayscale conversions
- Face straightening
- Face cropping (#Deepcae automatically do this while processing so no need to this)
- Image resizing
- Normalization
- Image enhancement with PIL like sharpening.
- image equalization.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So I couldn't understand, is jpg or png better? Because I have an image, then I save it (in one of the formats) and then give it to deepface so I can choose how to save it and I know jpg is lossy.

Comment: Png...use png..

Comment: About the filters you talked about, doesn't it do them inside the models? Should I check if adding the filters before, improves the results (per model)? I use ArcFace Facenet and SFace. Is there a specific filter the best to use?

Comment: Some basic filtering will be done by deepface....if your results are not accurate which means filtering done by deepface is not sufficient...you have to try each and every filter something like trail and error method..until u got good results

Comment: sharpening and grayscaling are the first methods to try...in past i worked with deepface for face recognition...i got very poor results are first because deepface usually crops images face part ending up blurry image which results poor face recognition...so I've applied image sharpening before feeding to deepface which got me better results